# Bootstrap 4 Left Stacked Tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs nav-stacked to get the look of the selected tab similar to [this](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-tabsleft.html).

Basically I need the look of the selected tab to be to the outside left of the content area which is to be a view with a border. Like it is sticking out of my view type of thing. Here is an example Plunk of what I have so far, but its not correct as the tabs are sitting inside of the bordered view:

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/cx920NdAtx0FrSq995E7?p=preview)

```
 <!-- myView is the container for my content-->
 <div id=myView>
 <!-- Nav tabs -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-2" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">Home content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">Profile content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Messages content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">Settings Conent</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this has me stumped and I'm not very experienced with this type of thing.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the elements in your external link and see what styles are applied?

Comment: I have checked it out, but its a different version of Bootstrap and its using a Twitter Bootstrap wizard plugin. The project I'm working on so far is requiring me to use Bootstrap v4 for now.